# attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnrecord;
Button btnstop;
MediaRecorder recorder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnrecord = findViewById(R.id.btnRecord);
    btnstop = findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    btnrecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            recorder = new MediaRecorder();

            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            recorder.setOutputFile(G.address + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".amr");

            try {
                recorder.prepare();
                recorder.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    btnstop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            recorder.release();
        }
    });
}
}
```

When I run it, it generates this error:

```
attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)' on a null object reference
```

for this line:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

I read similar questions and searched in web. Those where about initializing the MediaRecorder but I have initialized `recorder` . So i have no idea which part of my code is `null` that it gives me this error.  Can you please help me?

**UPDATE**

I just restart Android Studio and previous error is gone. Now this error is shown:

```
10-05 14:21:05.584 10855-10855/? E/Zygote: v2
10-05 14:21:05.584 10855-10855/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
10-05 14:21:22.964 10855-10855/com.pentester.myregm.recorder E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pentester.myregm.recorder, PID: 10855
java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._setAudioSource(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.java:488)
    at com.pentester.myregm.recorder.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:31)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5697)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10826)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22526)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

It's still for this line:

```
recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
```

Comment: can you post entire **stacktrace**?

Comment: Yes. I update the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing **runtime permission** of `Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO`, add that in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

You'll need to check that permission runtime and proceed further.

Comment: Then, you'll need to check it runtime. that's why the exception. becuase, it's not allowed